# How to dynamically created objects and access their pointer

Tags: c++

This might seem like a trivial issue, but I can't seem to find a solution.

What I have:

```
void VideoHandler::demoBurn(QString fileName) {

    // Create a reader for a video
    openshot::FFmpegReader r("raw_videos/example0.mp4");
    r.Open(); // Open the target reader

    // Create a writer
    openshot::FFmpegWriter w("edited_videos/NewVideo.mp4");
    w.SetAudioOptions(true, "libvorbis", 44100, 2, openshot::ChannelLayout::LAYOUT_STEREO, 128000);
    w.SetVideoOptions(true,"libx264" , openshot::Fraction(30,1), r.info.width, r.info.height, openshot::Fraction(1,1), false, false, 300000);
    w.Open();

    openshot::Timeline t(r.info.width,r.info.height, r.info.fps, 44100,2, openshot::ChannelLayout::LAYOUT_STEREO);
    
    // Clip example
    openshot::Clip c1(new openshot::QtImageReader("edited_videos/0.png"));
    c1.Layer(1);
    c1.Position(5.9);
    c1.Start(5.9);
    c1.End(10.0);
    c1.scale = openshot::SCALE_NONE;
    c1.gravity = openshot::GRAVITY_TOP_LEFT;
    c1.location_x = 0.0;
    c1.location_y = 0.2;

    std::list<openshot::Clip> clipList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        QString imageName = QString("edited_videos/%1.png").arg(i);
        clipList.push_back(openshot::Clip(new openshot::QtImageReader(imageName.toUtf8().toStdString())));
    }

    // Add clip values and add to timeline
    std::list<openshot::Clip>::iterator it;
    int test = 0;
    for (it = clipList.begin(); it != clipList.end(); it++) {
        it->Layer(1);
        if(test == 0) {
        it->Position(5.9);
        it->Start(5.9);
        it->End(10.0);
        } else {
            it->Position(10.0);
            it->Start(10.0);
            it->End(15.0);
        }
        it->scale = openshot::SCALE_NONE;
        it->gravity = openshot::GRAVITY_TOP_LEFT;
        it->location_x = 0.0;
        it->location_y = 0.2;
        test++;
        t.AddClip(&it);
    }


    // Add clips to timeline
    t.AddClip(&c1);

    openshot::Clip c2(new openshot::FFmpegReader("raw_videos/example0.mp4"));
    c2.Position(0.0);
    c2.Layer(0);
    t.AddClip(&c2);
    // Open the timeline reader
    t.Open();

    // Close the timeline reader

    w.WriteFrame(&t, 1, r.info.video_length);

    // Close the reader & writer
    t.Close();
    w.Close();
    r.Close();
}
```

I'm using [libopenshot](https://github.com/OpenShot/libopenshot) to burn some image overlays to the video, and since I don't know how many images there will be, I need to dynamically create a `openshot::Clip` for each one and give it some values.
I saw some examples on dynamic object allocation and thought this should work, but I'm getting compile errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136: error: use of deleted function ‘openshot::Clip::Clip(const openshot::Clip&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
/home/3rdparty/libopenshot/include/Clip.h:95: error: ‘juce::CriticalSection::CriticalSection(const juce::CriticalSection&)’ is private within this context
```

And for `t.AddClip(&it)` error:

```
cannot initialize a parameter of type 'openshot::Clip *' with an rvalue of type 'std::list<openshot::Clip>::iterator *' (aka '_List_iterator<openshot::Clip> *')
```

I can somewhat understand this error, but how do I give it the right pointer, I thought the `it` would hold the pointer to the object?

Since I never done dynamic object allocation, I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it, am I using a wrong type of `list`?

Comment: That a code uses Qt does not imply that the problem has to do with Qt. In your case if you change QString with std::string you would still have the problem. The idea of the tags is to attract the attention of the community on a specific topic and in this case Qt is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure it is irrelevant, since Qt has it's own list types, and as such, maybe one of them can work in this case.

Comment: But in your case the error message is obvious: `.... std::list<openshot::Clip>::iterator ...` the error is caused by std::list, if the error were in QList, QVector, etc then yes I would agree but in your case it is too obvious that not.

Comment: Now it's in QList...

Comment: Do not change code just to keep the qt tag, the change you try makes the error message inconsistent.

Comment: You already saw that the error has changed, and now the answer that was published (and the effort and time) do not make sense. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: Just proved you a point, nothing more, error is not inconsistent as I edited the error message as well.

Comment: And the effort that "eerorika" made is worth nothing? mmm, I mean the OP (I mean you) proposes a question for a certain error but in the middle it changes the code to keep a tag and show me I don't know what, and then you waste valuable time to another user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220642/discussion-between-light01-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> std::list<openshot::Clip>::iterator it;
> ...
> t.AddClip(&it);
> ```
>
> I thought the it would hold the pointer to the object?

When you use the addressof operator - i.e. the unary `&` operator - on a value, what you get is pointer to that object. In this case, you use `&it`, and therefore you get a pointer to `it`. `it` is an iterator to a list.

However, `AddClip` is not expecting a pointer to an iterator. It is expecting a pointer to a `openshot::Clip` object. That is why you get the error:

> cannot initialize a parameter of type [pointer to clip] with an rvalue of type [pointer to iterator]

I don't see how this could be affected by what the iterator "holds".

---

How might you get a pointer to a clip object? You apply the addressof operator on such object - rather than applying addressof operator on an object of some other type such as an iterator.

How might you get a clip object? You have an iterator to such object; you can indirect through the iterator to get the object.

How might you indirect through an iterator? You use the indirection operator i.e. the unary `*` operator.

For example:

```
t.AddClip(&*it);
```

---

> Since I never done dynamic object allocation, I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it

I don't know of *openshot*, so I cannot be certain, but those bare `new` expressions seem dubious. Unless that API mandates it, you should probably be using a unique pointer assuming dynamic allocation is needed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this `t.AddClip(&*it);` does fix the pointer issue.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error, I managed to get it to work. What I changed is:
created a list of pointers (doesn't matter if it's `QList` or `std:list`, tested and both work the same)

and re-referenced all the iteration objects with pointers to the actual object.
Thanks to @eerorika for the info about (&*it)

```
    QList<openshot::Clip*> clipList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        QString imageName = QString("edited_videos/%1.png").arg(i);
        clipList.push_back(new openshot::Clip(new openshot::QtImageReader(imageName.toUtf8().toStdString())));
    }

    // Add clip values and add to timeline
    QList<openshot::Clip*>::iterator it;
    int test = 0;
    for (it = clipList.begin(); it != clipList.end(); it++) {

        (*it)->Layer(1);
        if(test == 0) {
            (*it)->Position(5.9);
            (*it)->Start(5.9);
            (*it)->End(10.0);
        } else {
            (*it)->Position(10.0);
            (*it)->Start(10.0);
            (*it)->End(15.0);
        }
        (*it)->scale = openshot::SCALE_NONE;
        (*it)->gravity = openshot::GRAVITY_TOP_LEFT;
        (*it)->location_x = 0.0;
        (*it)->location_y = 0.2;
        test++;
        t.AddClip(&*(*it));
    }
```